# Update vue-toast-notification library

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working with `vue`, I installed vue-toast-notification library.

This is my code:

```
this.$toast.info(`<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i> start`)
looping -> send req and res status
this.$toast.info(`<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i> Building... ${status}`)
end looping
this.$toast.info(`done!`)
```

Every toast building shows on a new line.

I wish to see only the relevant response, I don't want the notification to pop every time. I only wish to see that the update was made successfully.

Comment: Please send more information. it's better to write the whole component in your question.

Answer (score 0):

do you need create const toast like this:

```
  const toast = this.$toast.default(
     `<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i> start`,
      { duration: 0, dismissible: false }
  )
```

and update like this:

```
toast.message =`<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i> Building... ${status}`
```

after loop:

```
toast.message =`done!`
```